# Apache Thrift with nodejs example

Tags: node.js, serialization, deserialization, thrift

I am trying to use Apache Thrift for passing messages between applications implemented in different languages. It is not necessarily used as RPC, but more for serializing/deserializing messages. 
One application is in node.js. I am trying to figure out how Apache thrift works with node.js, but I can't find too much documentation and examples, except for one tiny one regarding Cassandra at:
https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/trunk/lib/nodejs

Again, I don't need any procedures declared in the .thrift file, I only need to serialize a simple data structure like:

```
struct Notification {
   1: string subject,
   2: string message
 }
```

Can anyone help me with an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above answer is wrong, because it tries to use outBuffers directly, which is an array of buffers.  Here is a working example of using thrift with nodejs:

```
var util = require('util');
var thrift = require('thrift');

var Notification = require('./gen-nodejs/notification_types.js').Notification;

var TFramedTransport = require('thrift/lib/thrift/transport').TFramedTransport;
var TBufferedTransport = require('thrift/lib/thrift/transport').TBufferedTransport;
var TBinaryProtocol = require('thrift/lib/thrift/protocol').TBinaryProtocol;

var transport = new TFramedTransport(null, function(byteArray) {
  // Flush puts a 4-byte header, which needs to be parsed/sliced.
  byteArray = byteArray.slice(4);

  // DESERIALIZATION:
  var tTransport = new TFramedTransport(byteArray);
  var tProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(tTransport);
  var receivedNotification = new Notification();
  receivedUser.read(tProtocol);

  console.log(util.inspect(receivedNotification, false, null));
});

var binaryProt = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);

// SERIALIZATION:
var notification = new Notification({"subject":"AAAA"});
console.log(util.inspect(notification, false, null));
notification.write(binaryProt);
transport.flush();
```

Comment: Sorry, but you deserialize in the same script the same data which were created. But if use some intermediate storage ( rabbitmq ) what data exactly to store in rabbit? Sliced outBuffers? Or call each time flush and in callback save data? And use slice for byteArray is not good idea every time because it not copy data, but make reference to it.

Answer (score 6):

I finally found the answer to this question, after wasting a lot of time just by looking at the library for nodejs.

```
//SERIALIZATION:
var buffer = new Buffer(notification);
var transport = new thrift.TFramedTransport(buffer);
var binaryProt = new thrift.TBinaryProtocol(transport);
notification.write(binaryProt);
```

At this point, the byte array can be found in the transport.outBuffers field:

```
var byteArray = transport.outBuffers;
```

For deserialization:

```
var tTransport = new thrift.TFramedTransport(byteArray);
var tProtocol = new thrift.TBinaryProtocol(tTransport);
var receivedNotif = new notification_type.Notification();
receivedNotif.read(tProtocol);
```

Also the following lines need to be added to the index.js file from the nodejs library for thrift:

```
exports.TFramedTransport = require('./transport').TFramedTransport;
exports.TBufferedTransport = require('./transport').TBufferedTransport;
exports.TBinaryProtocol = require('./protocol').TBinaryProtocol;
```

Plus there is also at least one bug in the nodejs library.

Answer (score 1):

DigitalGhost is right, the previous example is wrong. 
IMHO the outBuffers is a private property to the transport class and should not be accessed.